# When are objects popped from a list destroyed?

Tags: c++, stl

This may well be a really silly/basic question, but I can't really figure it out. I'll tell you what I think - please correct me if/where I'm wrong.

When we're using STL containers to store *raw* pointers, we have to take care of cleaning up after them:

```
std::list<animal*> alist;
animal *a = new animal();
alist.push_back(a);
...
animal *b = alist.front();
alist.pop_front();
//do stuff with b
delete b;
```

What happens if we store objects? It is my understanding that if a container full of objects goes out of scope, all the objects inside it are destroyed. Correct?

But what if we remove an object from a container, using `std::list<T>.pop_front()` for example?

```
std::list<animal> alist;
{
  animal ani();
  //ani is inserted at the end of the list (it IS ani rather than a copy 
  //since push_back accepts const T&)
  alist.push_back(ani);
} //nothing is deallocated/destroyed here
...
{
  animal b = alist.front(); //b is now a copy(?!) of the front element
                            //created via copy constructor
  alist.pop_front(); //the front element of the list is 
                     //destroyed/destructor is called 
  //do stuff with b
} //b goes out of scope
```

Comment: What is your question? As for the `copy` you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you store something in a container, whatever you pass is copied into the container<sup>1</sup>. You still own the original object<sup>2</sup>; the container owns its copy of the object. It's true that `push_back` (for one example) takes its parameter by reference. This means when you pass your object to be pushed into the container, no copy is needed for use as the parameter itself, but what's put into the container is still a copy of what you told it to push. Passing by reference means only *one* copy is needed; if it was passed by value, (at least in C++98/03) that would have resulted in *two* copies: one copy from your object to the function argument, then another copy from the function argument into the container. Passing by reference allows a single copy directly from your original object directly into the container.

Likewise, when you get an object from the container, you're getting a copy of what was in the container. The container still has its object, and you have your object. Each of these has its own lifetime.

When you erase or pop an object from a container, that object is removed from the container and destroyed -- if it's something that has a destructor, the destructor will be called to destroy it.

The objects in a container will be destroyed when the container itself is destroyed. Your object will be destroyed whenever it happens to be -- the fact that it came from a container has no effect on that. If it's a local variable, it'll be destroyed when it goes out of scope. If it's a global, it'll last 'til the end of time (for the program). If you return it from a function and that's used to initialize a reference, the normal rule for extending its lifetime there will be observed. Bottom line: at that point, it's just another object, that'll have a lifetime just like any other object defined in the same way.

This can get a little...fuzzy when/if you store pointers (raw or smart) in a container. All of the above actually remains true, *but* the object being copied/stored is a pointer. Unless you use some container that's "aware" that you're storing pointers (e.g., Boost ptr_vector) it's just dealing with a pointer, and "ignoring" the fact that somewhere out there is an object that the pointer refers to.

---

1. In C++11, you can use, for example, `emplace_back` to construct an object in place in the container, but the same basic idea applies -- the container has an object that it owns, and you never touch directly.
2. Here I'm using "object" more like a non-programmer would -- just to mean "some thing",  not necessarily an instance of a class. It may not even be an "object" in the sense that C uses the word -- it could be a pure rvalue (e.g., `push_back(10)`).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the copying? `push_back` for example accepts a `const T& newelement`, which to me strongly suggests that no copying is done!

Comment: @us2012: When you use push_back, it doesn't need to make a copy for passing to push_back itself, but what goes into the container is still a copy. If it passed by value, it'd end up making *two* copies (copy once to the parameter, then again to the container). Of course, with move semantics, C++11 could pass by value and still only make one copy, but push_back predates that capability (and even so, with some types a move from the parameter to the container would still involve copying).

Comment: @us2012 `push_back` copies the object internally. It only takes the object by reference to avoid copying it _twice_, once when being passed into the function and once when being put into the container. Remember that the identity of an object is its location in memory, there is no way get the local object (on the stack) into the container (somewhere on the heap) without copying it (or moving it, but that's still a different object).

Comment: I'm accepting this one because, together with the comments, it explains best what I was looking for. It would be great if you could integrate that comment (and an explicit mention that `pop` destroys the copy in the container) into your answer!

Comment: Small extra question: Am I correct in thinking that if I want to replicate the Java semantics of a `Container<Object>`, the closest equivalent in C++11  would be `Container<std::shared_ptr<Object> >`?

Comment: @us2012: My Java is rusty enough that I hesitate to say with certainty, but yes, that sounds fairly close (with the proviso that shared_ptr uses reference counting, where Java uses tracing garbage collection).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you store objects and not pointers pointing to dynamic memory then you do not need to do any deallocations.
When you pop the element. The standard library takes care to call the destructor for the popped object.

The rule is:
You just need to deallocate(*call `delete`*) if you allocated something(*called `new`*).

Answer (score 2):

> It is my understanding that if a container full of objects goes out of scope, so do all the objects contained in it. Correct?

Firstly, some important pedantry.  *Objects* don't go out of scope, *identifiers* do.  This is an important distinction, which may help clarify what's going on here:

When the identifier (variable) corresponding to a container goes out of scope, the corresponding object (the container itself) is automatically deleted.  Its destructor then deletes each of its elements in turn.

> But what if we remove an object from a container, using `std::list<T>.pop_front()` for example?

The container simply deletes the contained element (as far as you're concerned, it calls its destructor).  (There may be other housekeeping as well, such as shuffling all the remaining elements along by one in a `std::vector`, which incurs lots of destructor/copy-constructor calls).

Comment: I will update my question accordingly - what I meant of course is "the objects are destroyed".

Answer (score 2):

If you remove an object from a STL container, its destructor is called if it's a struct/class-type.  Also depending on the container, the internal data-structure used to store the object is deallocated/destroyed as well.

Keep in mind that pointer-types are not struct/class-types and therefore do not have destructors that can manage the memory being pointed to.  Therefore if you want to avoid accidental memory leaks when removing pointers from an STL container, it's best to use a smart-pointer type such as `std::shared_ptr<T>` that will properly manage the memory allocated to the pointer, and deallocate it when there are no more references to the allocated memory object.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::list<animal> alist;
// A list is created in automatic storage (the stack).  Its elements
// will exist in the free store (the heap)
{
  animal ani;
  // ani is created in automatic storage (the stack)

  alist.push_back(ani);
  // A copy of ani (using animal(const animal&) ctor) is created in
  // the list "alist" via memory allocated on the free store (the heap)

} // ani.~animal() is called, then the storage for ani is recycled
// (ie, the stack space that ani used can be reused)

{
  animal b = alist.front();
  // either animal(animal&) or animal(animal const&)
  // is called on the previous line, constructing an instance
  // of animal called "b" in automatic storage (the stack)
  // This is a copy of a copy of the animal instance called "ani"
  // above, assuming nothing else besides this code has manipulated
  // alist

  alist.pop_front();
  // The animal in the alist that is a copy of ani is destroyed
  // from the free store (the heap)


  //do stuff with b
} // b.~animal() is called, then the memory in automatic storage
// (the stack) that b lived in is recycled for other purposes
```